# Flight time changed without notification - compensation?

Tags: bookings, delays, compensation, flight-status

I have a flight booked today at 6:50 and received an email yesterday asking me to check in for 7:55. The flight number is the same but the flight time apparently was changed. The only trace of my original flight time is my booking confirmation which says clearly the former time. I'm aware that companies may change times but I thought they at least have to notify you when they do.

So my question is, is this simply bad service or actually a case for compensation? For example due to the later arrival time I now have to book a taxi instead of train which is more costly. If they had notified me in time I would have refunded the flight and book an earlier one. I'm based in EU and the flight was between EU countries.

Comment: It's neither.  A change of ~1hr is not all uncommon and likely not even a  'change in schedule' just an operational delay.

Answer (score 2):

For a delay of just over an hour, sorry, **there's no grounds for compensation**.  EU delay compensation rules only kick in after a delay of over 3 hours: [Air passenger rights](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#apr-problems).

The airline's promise is to get you to your destination or refund your money, so those are your only options.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that. My point is that they did not notify me about the change in schedule and I wonder if that's normal. I think they should write me an email or call me at the very least. It is not a delay but a change in schedule.

Comment: But you received a notification yesterday, no?

Comment: No they asked me to check in, they did not inform me about the change in flight time. They basically treat the issue as if nothing has happened at all and there would have been no change in the first place. Only my booking confirmation still proves that I booked for an earlier time. It's not labeled a delay, it's simply the same flight number wth a later departure.